# SQLiteNetExtensions OneToMany and ManyToOne Relationships not working

Tags: c#, sqlite, sqlite-net, sqlite-net-extensions

I have a problem with SQLite-Net
I have three classes: ClassA, ClassB, ClassC.
ClassA has OneToMany relation with ClassB.
ClassB has ManyToOne Relation with ClassC.

This is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using SQLite.Net.Attributes;
using SQLiteNetExtensions.Attributes;
using WardFlex.Core.DAL.Interfaces;

    public class ClassA : IEntity
    {
        [XmlAttribute("Id")]
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public Int64 Id { get; set; }

        public string Kaka { get; set; }

        [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
        public  List<ClassB> ClassBs { get; set; }
    }


    public class ClassB : IEntity
    {
        [XmlAttribute("Id")]
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public Int64 Id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(typeof(ClassA))]
        public Int64 ClassAId { get; set; }

        [ManyToOne]
        public  ClassA ClassA { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(typeof(ClassC))]
        public Int64 ClassCId { get; set; }

        [ManyToOne]
        public ClassC ClassC { get; set; }
    }        

public class ClassC : IEntity
{
    [XmlAttribute("Id")]
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }

    [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
    public List<ClassB> ClassBs { get; set; }
}
```

I Save ClassA entity, but
When I try GetAllWithChildren From ClassARepository I can't to see classC entity from ClassB(image was attached)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbn1V.png)

What could be the problem??

Thank you in advance

Comment: Mapping seems OK to me, are you sure that you use InsertWithChildren on save because if not it might be a case where you don't save all the data in first place.

There are tools to open sqlite database that work fine so I'd advice to check there if you haven't done so already (personally I use a firefox extension).

In our project all these cascade operations were not performing very well so at the end we ended up doing a lot of the stuff that usually the ORM does manually. And we stopped using WithChildren.

Comment: Also check if you're using WithChildren version of the get method when you're getting the data, otherwise you'll have only the key value (not getting the reference objects)

Comment: In my code I use to save item method 
InsertOrReplaceWithChildren(item , recursive: true);
And I use to get items method
GetAllWithChildren<T>(null,true);
And it does not work

Answer (score 0):

With SQLite-Net, relationships are not fetched automatically, you have to fetch them manually with `GetChildren` method or use any of the `GetWithChildren` methods with the `recursive` flag set to true to load the entire model tree.

Take a look at the `RecursiveReadTests` and `RecursiveWriteTests` files in the [Integration Tests Project](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/src/9b65308fa6a95cbc9fd9dce8c222efa5c1b8ff7b/IntegrationTests.Touch/Tests/?at=master) for samples.

**UPDATE:** You have not set your recursive policy on `ClassB` `ManyToOne` relationship to `ClassC`. Try adding the `CascadeOperationsFlag` for working with recursive operations:

```
[ManyToOne(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
public ClassC ClassC { get; set; }
```

It's also a good idea to use only `CascadeRead` operation or set `ReadOnly` mode to true on relationships that are saved manually. For example, your `ClassBs` property of `ClassC` doesn't need any write operation:

```
[OneToMany(ReadOnly = true)]
public List<ClassB> ClassBs { get; set; }
```

This will avoid you problems where saving `ClassC` objects may delete relationships when saving an unset property.

Comment: In my code I use to save item method 
InsertOrReplaceWithChildren(item , recursive: true);
And I use to get items method
GetAllWithChildren<T>(null,true);
And it does not work

Comment: Can you share the code where you insert and fetch the elements from database? The models seem fine.

Comment: public Boolean SaveItem(T item)
        {
            lock (this.locker)
            {
                try
                {
                    this.InsertOrReplaceWithChildren(item , recursive: true);

                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    if (logger != null)
                    {
                        logger.Error(e, String.Format("{0} - Entity:{1}", e.Message, typeof(T).Name));
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

Comment: public IList<T> GetItems()
        {
            lock (this.locker)
            {
                return this.GetAllWithChildren<T>(null,true);
            }
        }